# PyCharm does not recognize the return type of a decorated function?

Tags: python, pycharm, decorator, python-typing

I am trying to decorate a method of a python class:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


def my_decorator(func: Callable[..., T]) -> Callable[..., T]:
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args: Any) -> T:
        print("decorator")
        print("Before the method is called")
        result = func(*args)
        print("After the method is called")
        return result

    return wrapped


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, param):
        super().__init__()
        self.param = param

    @my_decorator
    def bar(self, x: int) -> str:
        return str(self.param + x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Foo(2)
    res = a.bar(1)
```

However, I realized PyCharm does not recognize the return type of the method (the hint/autocomplete does not work). However if I do the following instead

```
    def bar(self, x: int) -> str:
        return str(self.param + x)

    bar = my_decorator(bar)
```

PyCharm recognizes the return type correctly. What is the difference between these two cases? Is there a way to make PyCharm deduce the types in the first (more compact) implementation?

Comment: This works well in [`mypy`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=a12c5f040d64bc0abfd06a4082ee9f8f) and is PEP-compliant, so must be a `PyCharm` bug. [This one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-48338/Parameter-hint-shows-args-kwargs-for-a-decorated-function-call) looks similar. Please update your `PyCharm`, then check an issue tracker and open a new ticket if this is still a problem.

Comment: Consider also preserving full signature (like [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=abcbbad99f8870374aa8cfe24fcb75e1)).

Comment: Yes looks like it is a PyCharm bug (I have the latest version)